# svn post-commit Permission denied

Tags: svn

Currently i'm trying to setup a post-commit hook that automatically exports the svn copy to my www-root so that my website will be updated after a commit is done.
The post-commit hook looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Delete Old site
rm -R /var/www/html/sha
print 1
# Export Repository
svn export --force file:///var/local/svn /var/www/html/sha

# Make sure Apache Owns the website
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/sha
```

But i get a lot of Permission denied errors when i commit something. Basically like this:

```
rm: cannot remove '/var/www/html/sha/extensions/LdapAuthentication.php': Permission denied
```

So i know that i need to set some new permissions but i'm not sure what permissions i have do set. the /var/www/html directory has www-data:www-data as user:group.

I connect to the svn server via tunneling meaning svh+ssh://user@host/repo

Any clues?

Okay it seems to work now. I changed the owner of the /var/www/html/sha directory to www-data:walter and remove the chown command, because you need sudo for that anyways. Works like a charm now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The user account which the hook script runs under needs to have the appropriate permissions on that path.

If you use Apache to serve your repository, then the account that process runs under needs the permissions. If you use svnserve, that user account needs the permissions.

It's also possible that you have another process holding a lock on a file or directory, blocking the ability to delete it.

Comment: Okay. i tried to get the user which runs svnserve with ps aux | grep svn but it does not show up. It has to run because i can use svn.. Another way to find out which user needs the permissions?

Comment: How do you access the repository? If you don't use an `svn://` URL, then I wouldn't expect svnserve to be running. Is it started on-demand by inetd, perhaps?

Comment: I using svn+ssh:// so there should be an svnserve. If the post-commit hooks exports the svn to the directory the rights looks like this: `-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data walter   2034 Jan 15 15:08 index.php` From what i understand here is that the owner is www-data which is in the group walter. What i don't understand is why the group here is `walter`, because www-data isn't even in this group. if i change the group of the files to www-data the post-commit script runs until `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/sha`

Comment: If you're using `svn+ssh://` (this is good info to edit into the original post), it gets wonky. svnserve isn't running constantly in this case - it'll be started by `sshd` when you make the connection. The SSH user account which is committing is the one under which the hook script will execute. You're going to need to read up [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sshauth) to sort out who's doing what in this situation (I haven't done svn+ssh myself, so I can't do much more than point at the docs without risking steering you wrong)

Comment: Thanks so far. I will edit it. The website says `and is now invoking a private svnserve process as that user`. So the user should be walter who invokes the svnserve process. still i don't get why the owner is www-data and the group is walter. You got any clue? Thanks so far!

Comment: Okay it seems to work now. I changed the owner of the /var/www/html/sha directory to www-data:walter and remove the chown command, because you need sudo for that anyways. Works like a charm now. Thanks!